# Magento 2.3 Install Venia Data error in setup:upgrade commands

Tags: magento2.2.3, pwa, pwa-studio, venia

I am applying the PWA Venia theme on local setup via xampp (windows10).

I have referred the following guidelines:
https://magento-research.github.io/pwa-studio/venia-pwa-concept/setup/

Adding the Venia sample data modules to Magento is successful.But when I run the setup:upgrade command then following error occurs in the commandline

> Module 'Magento_ConfigurableSampleDataVenia':
>   in C:\xampp-7.2.19\htdocs\mage232\vendor\magento\module-configurable-sample-data-venia\Setup\Swatches.php on line 116

Comment: You have which version of Magento2 ?

Answer (score 3):

Set file system ownership and permissions again as a user with root privileges.

Don’t install sample data in production mode. Switch to developer mode and clear var(cached files) directories and try again.

Enter the following commands in the order shown as the Magento file system owner:

```
$cd <magento_root>
$bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
$rm -rf generated/code/* generated/metadata/*
$bin/magento sampledata:deploy
```

For more details [refer](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/trouble/tshoot_sample-data.html).Hope this helps you.

Comment: this is perfect answer even i have used this and solved my problem.